# How to solve ORA-01031 - Error When Creating New User PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, createuser

I am trying to create new user in PL/SQL.  I am getting an error as follows:

[image: error]

Answer (score 3):

User you use to create another user doesn't have required privileges.

In Oracle, such a "privileged" user is SYS. For example:

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USERS

SQL> create user brisime identified by blabla
  2  default tablespace users
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL>
```

If I try to do the same as a non-privileged user (i.e. the one that doesn't have `create user` privilege), it'll fail:

```
SQL> drop user brisime;

User dropped.

SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> create user brisime identified by blabla
  2  default tablespace users
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on users;
create user brisime identified by blabla
                                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


SQL>
```

But, if SYS grants `create user` to `scott`, Scott will also be able to do that:

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> grant create user to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> create user brisime identified by blabla
  2  default tablespace users
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL>
```

Therefore, make sure to acquire required privileges before trying to create user.

The same goes for *altering* the user - you need to have those privileges.